# An example of center of a ring is not two sided ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

[image]

I proved the first part of the question. Can you help me to find an example for the second part?

Comment: What examples of rings did you try?

Answer (score 2):

$1$ is always in the centre.

The only way for the centre to be an ideal is if it is the entire ring (i.e. the ring is commutative). Any non-commutative ring is a counterexample.

Comment: A ring may not contain $1$. But every non-commutative ring with $1$ is indeed a counterexample.

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much.

Comment: @markvs: I think (or at least hope) that it is still customary (or at least much more common) for the unqualified term "ring" to mean "ring with 1". I always use the term "rng" for a structure that satisfies all the ring laws except the existence of $1$.

Comment: @RobArthan: I once edited, as a chief editor, a paper with rng in the title. I did accept the paper, but only because the content was exceptionally good. In general such a paper would be automatically rejected.

Comment: @markvs: I agree that "rng" is a term that merits a reminder before use (and hence is not very appropriate in the title of a paper). In this case, I guess my main point should have been that if the OP is working with rings that are assumed to contain $1$, then your comment might be somewhat confusing. It's a shame that "not necessarily unital rings" is a mouthful and "rng" is an in-joke. At least we're all agreed that fields are all commutative (unless we are writing for a French-speaking audience $\ddot{\smile}$).